# Is the sum of a bunch of random variables obeying some certain distributions, say U(-C,C), each of which has a different 'C', a normal distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a bunch of uniform distributions (or you can consider that an infinite number of uniform distributions), each of which has a form of *U*(-*C*,*C*), with the value of *C* different from each other. Is the sum of them a normal distribution?

---

The above question is using the wrong expressions. I hope it didn't make you confounded.

I have a bunch of random variables (or you can consider that an infinite number of random variables), each of which obeys a uniform distribution *U*(-*C*,*C*), with the value of *C* different from each other. Is the sum of these random variables obeys a normal distribution?

Comment: Consider what happens if the $C$s go to zero very fast...

Comment: @NateEldredge Well, that would be a problem, but I suggest that we not go to that extreme. But can it be proved that the sum of them follow a normal distribution by using the central limit theorem?

Comment: The sum of at least two distributions is never a distribution. Perhaps you are confusing random variables with their distributions -- which are related but very different things.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Yes, I realize that I confused them, and I was asking about the random variables.

Comment: @ddKong : The central limit theorem involves the limiting distribution involving a sum of finitely many random variables, as the number of terms in the sum approaches infinity. In the most well known version, they all have the SAME distribution and they are independent. And it's not the distribution of the sum of the terms, but rather of the result of first summing the terms, then subtracting the expected value of the sum (which depends on the number of terms) and then dividing by the standard deviation of the sum (which depends on the number of terms). $\qquad$

Comment: What in the world does it mean to ask a question and then say it is using the wrong expressions?  Should the first paragraph be deleted?  If so, then you should do it!

Answer (score 3):

The sum of independent  uniformly distributed variables has a Fourier transform that vanishes at some points. Hence it can never have a normal distribution.

Comment: I am not a mathematician, but according to the central limit theorem, the sum of an infinite number of uniform distributions which are i.d.d. does finally forms a normal distribution. Am I right or not?

Comment: @ddKong: Then you're probably posting on the wrong site. This site is for questions in research mathematics.

Comment: @ddKong: A finite or infinite sum of the form $\sum_i X_i$ where $X_i \sim U(-c_i, c_i)$ cannot be normal for any sequence $c_i$, as Yuval shows.  The central limit theorem is about a *sequence* of *normalized* sums, like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, where the $c_i$ should all be "comparable" in some sense.  It is in a certain sense like a sum of iid $U(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ where $\epsilon$ is *infinitesimal*, but that should not be taken too literally (unless you want to do nonstandard analysis).

Comment: @NateEldredge I realize that I was wrong.